# The purpose of updating after adding a ppa repository

Tags: ppa, repository

When adding a ppa repository using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:...`, why should I execute `sudo apt-get update`?

I am new to Ubuntu and I don't see the purpose of it because there aren't packages installed from the repo. It only takes a lot of time to cycle through my installed packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manpages:

```
update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources.
           The indexes of available packages are fetched from the location(s) specified
           in /etc/apt/sources.list. For example, when using a Debian archive, this
           command retrieves and scans the Packages.gz files, so that information about
           new and updated packages is available. An update should always be performed
           before an upgrade or dist-upgrade. Please be aware that the overall progress
           meter will be incorrect as the size of the package files cannot be known in
           advance.
```

Adding `apt-add-repository` just adds a line to `/etc/apt/source.list`.

`apt-get update` downloads the latest package index from all the known repositories

Also I recommend reading [apt-get wiki pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)